# Can I patch bibunits \putbib so that I can generate separate groups of references?

Tags: bibtex, bibunits, splitbib

I would like to find out whether it is at all possible to patch `bibunits` to mimic bibtopic functionality (i.e. multiple and filterable bibliography commands)

I think there might be a way to duplicate `\putbib` if I can apply a filter on

```
\def\bu@bibdata{\jobname}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \iflabelstoglobalaux
  \else
    \let\orig@bibliography\bibliography
    \def\bibliography#1{%
      \if@filesw
        \immediate\openout\@bibunitaux bu.aux
        \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{bu.aux}}%
      \fi
      \orig@bibliography{#1}%
      \if@filesw
        \immediate\closeout\@bibunitaux
      \fi
    }%
  \fi
  \let\std@bibliography\bibliography
}
```

The reason this is so complex/difficult to solve is the the large sweeping document structure:

- In the preface of the document, there is a list of publications (this used to be a bibunit, but now it has to be broken into journal papers and abstracts) so bibunit so this requirement is why I started looking into bibtopics, but I have also opened a parallel question here (Can I patch bibunits \putbib so that I can generate seperate groups of references?) incase it is more practical to reprogram \putbib.
- The first part is its own IEEE bibunit (chapter level bibliography).
- The second part is it's own IEEE bibunit (section level bibliography - chapter free part).
- Part three has two bibunits (one per each chapter) and the second bibunit requires a custom citation style and bst file that I wrote myself by merging nature and IEEE bst files. It is this uniquely styled and presented chapter that prevents me from using biblatex and refsections.
- The last part has it's own bibunit (chapter level)

I can't use the structure below because it won't allow me to use IEEE ordering, it can't by definition.

I have read through the package documentation and I would hope that I could redefine a new command based on `putbib` to work with restrictions, similar to maybe splitbib (which is incompatible with bibunits).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibtopic}

\usepackage[numbers,square,comma,sort&compress,nonamebreak]{natbib}

\begin{document}


\begin{btUnit}
    \section{Testing}
    Let’s cite all the journal papers \cite{A, B}; and abstracts: \cite{C, D}.
    \citet{A}
    \begin{btSect}[IEEEtranNSB]{Journals}
        \section*{References from journals}
        \btPrintCited
    \end{btSect}

    \begin{btSect}{Abstracts}
        \section*{Abstracts from conferences}
        \btPrintCited
    \end{btSect}

\end{btUnit}


\begin{btUnit}
    \section{2 test}
    Let’s cite all the journal papers \cite{A, B}; and abstracts:   \cite{C, D}.

    \begin{btSect}[IEEEtranNSB]{Journals,Abstracts,CombinedBibFile}
        \section*{All references}
        \btPrintCited
    \end{btSect}
\end{btUnit}    




\end{document}
```

Comment: Again, Biblatex/Biber would make this *much* easier... `refsection`, `refsegment`, filters to sort by keyword, by category, by type, customised and combined bibliography filters....

Comment: @cfr The only thing holding me back is mixing bibliography citation styles.  Customized versions of IEEE and nature mixed with IEEE.  Can't seem to determine whether I can set this at the `refsection` level and if I will be able to customize the bibliography grammar with `biblatex`.  I have been using bibunits so far because each bibunit can be passed in [] a bst file.